# Sequence File with Block Compression

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I need to enable Sequence File with Block Compression data. Below is the table which will be stored as SequenceFile.

```
create table lip_data_quality
( buyer_id bigint,
  total_chkout bigint,
  total_errpds bigint
 )
 partitioned by (dt string)
row format delimited fields terminated by '\t'
stored as sequencefile
location '/apps/hdmi-technology/b_apdpds/lip-data-quality'
;
```

And in the above table, I am getting data in Compressed Form like this by enabling these commands-

```
set mapred.output.compress=true;
set mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK;
set mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.LzoCodec;
```

So my question is that's all I need to enable BLOCK Compression with Sequence File? Or is there anything else I need to do? I was following this article [Hadoop](http://books.google.com/books?id=H3mvcxPeUfwC&pg=PA172&lpg=PA172&dq=Sequence+Files+with+BLOCK+compression&source=bl&ots=pXtKy9-Kuc&sig=IFMfUAcW6XfA2TY8zvBhMyNjfic&hl=en&sa=X&ei=sakaUMAGhNHhBJ7AgMAN&ved=0CHIQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=Sequence%20Files%20with%20BLOCK%20compression&f=false)

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

**Update:-**

I am loading the data in the above table like this by putting everything in a `.hql file` and running that `hql file` from the shell command prompt. And changing the partition date everytime while running the below hql file.

```
set mapred.output.compress=true;
set mapred.output.compression.type=BLOCK;
set mapred.output.compression.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.LzoCodec;

insert overwrite table lip_data_quality partition (dt='20120712') 
SELECT query here which will give the output for the above table.
```

Comment: how are you loading data into the above table?

Comment: I have updated my question with the details that specifically answer your question. let me know if you need any more details.

Answer (score 1):

That should be fine then. You can also verify it by looking at the files on HDFS. There should be a directory in HDFS named /user/hive/warehouse/lip_data_quality/dt=20120712 after your load. If you run

```
hadoop fs -cat
```

on one of the files in that folder you should be able to see the header of the file which will  give you basic info on the file.

Comment: Thanks Paul for the information. I have one more doubt, so this is the best way to achieve the compression in Hive meaning efficient way of storing data in Hive?? and also how can I see all these files. One option is I am aware of `hadoop fs -text` on one of the files. But how I can decompress that file so that whenever I want to scp that file to windows I can clearly see the file in any notepad editor.

Comment: hadoop fs -text should take care of the decompression. As far as clearly seeing the file on windows, it should be readable but I think hive use control characters for separators. Its easy enough to try out though. As far as an efficient way of storing data. Sequence files work well because they are splittable which helps query performance and compression saves on disk but doesn't really do much for query performance. There are so many options for file storage in hadoop. Your specific requirements will drive what works best.

Answer (score 0):

Set the below properties before submitting job.

- setProperty(job, "mapred.output.compress", "true");
- setProperty(job,"mapred.output.compression.type", "BLOCK");
- setProperty(job,"mapred.output.compression.codec","org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec");

Using DefaultCodec, one can use org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.LzoCodec;